# When given the dimensions of a cylinder (A x B x C) what does each letter represent?

Tags: geometry

When looking at fire extinguishers online, the dimensions are always listed in the above format (A x B x C).

What does each letter represent?

Example: 3" x 5.5" x 14.9"

I assume the third (C) is height; I would think that (A) and (B) are perhaps diameter or circumference, but mathematically the numbers do not correspond (i.e. 3*pi != 5.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give them in length x width x height. You can think of it as the smallest bounding rectangular prism that would fit the entire extinguisher.

Comment: Given that a cylinder is as wide as it is long, does the difference in my example between (A) and (B) then likely exist because of the head on the extinguisher?

Comment: Yes, the head of the extinguisher and the hose. See the product details at the following link for an example:

http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/safety/fire-gas-water-protection/fire-extinguishers/fire-extinguisher-dry-chemical-10-lb?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQjwj7q6BRDcxfG4pNTQ2NoBEiQAzUpuW7xR24zjT-mxUgHd24wZ-y1t4EVGR3HJReL2khFfGeMaAurg8P8HAQ